# How to use type refinements for io-ts on input data?

Tags: typescript, validation, types

I am using [io-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/) to define my typescript types, in order to do runtime type validation and type declarations from a single source.

In this usecase I would like to define an interface with a string member and that member should validate against a regular expression, e.g. a version string. So valid input would look like this:

```
{version: '1.2.3'}
```

The mechanism to do this seems to be via branded types and I came up with this:

```
import { isRight } from 'fp-ts/Either';
import { brand, Branded, string, type, TypeOf } from 'io-ts';

interface VersionBrand {
  readonly Version: unique symbol; // use `unique symbol` here to ensure uniqueness across modules / packages
}

export const TypeVersion = brand(
  string, // a codec representing the type to be refined
  (value: string): value is Branded<string, VersionBrand> =>
    /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/.test(value), // a custom type guard using the build-in helper `Branded`
  'Version' // the name must match the readonly field in the brand
);

export const TypeMyStruct = type({
  version: TypeVersion,
});

export type Version = TypeOf<typeof TypeVersion>;
export type MyStruct = TypeOf<typeof TypeMyStruct>;

export function callFunction(data: MyStruct): boolean {
  // type check
  const validation = TypeMyStruct.decode(data);
  return isRight(validation);
}
```

This works as expected for type validation inside my `callFunction` method but I cannot invoke the function using a regular object, i.e. the following does not compile:

```
callFunction({ version: '1.2.3' });
```

This is failing with `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Branded<string, VersionBrand>'`.

While the error message makes sense, because `Version` is a specialization of `string` I would like to allow a caller to invoke the function with any string and then do a runtime validation that would check against the regular expression. Still I'd like to have some typing information, so I would not like to define the input as `any`.

Ideally there would be a way to derive a version `VersionForInput` from `Version` that uses the primitive data types for the branded fields, so it would be equivalent to:

```
interface VersionForInput { version: string }
```

Of course I could declare it explicitly but this would mean to duplicate the type definition to some extend.

**Question:** Is there a way in io-ts to derive an unbranded version from a branded version of a type? Is the use of a branded type even the right choice for this usecase? The goal is to do extra validation on top of a primitive type (e.g. extra regexp checks for a string value).

Answer (score 0):

I think you've asked sort of two questions so I'll try to answer both.

### Extracting the the base type from a branded type

It is possible to introspect on which `io-ts` codec is being branded via the `type` field on an instance of `Brand`.

```js
TypeVersion.type // StringType
```

So it would be possible to write a function that consumes your struct type and creates a codec from the base. You could also extract the type using something like this:

```js
import * as t from 'io-ts';
type BrandedBase<T> = T extends t.Branded<infer U, unknown> ? U : T;
type Input = BrandedBase<Version>; // string
```

### Using the branded type

But I think instead of defining things in this way, I would instead define my struct input type and then define a refinement so that you only have to specify the parts of the codec that are refined from the input. This would be using the newer `io-ts` api.

```js
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function';
import * as D from 'io-ts/Decoder';
import * as t from 'io-ts';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';

const MyInputStruct = D.struct({
  version: D.string,
});

interface VersionBrand {
  readonly Version: unique symbol; // use `unique symbol` here to ensure uniqueness across modules / packages
}
const isVersionString = (value: string): value is t.Branded<string, VersionBrand> => /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/.test(value);
const VersionType = pipe(
  D.string,
  D.refine(isVersionString, 'Version'),
);

const MyStruct = pipe(
  MyInputStruct,
  D.parse(({ version }) => pipe(
    VersionType.decode(version),
    E.map(ver => ({
      version: ver,
    })),
  )),
);
```

This would define the input type first, and then define a refinement on the input type to be your stricter internal decoder. If you had other values you could `...rest` them through in the `E.map` to avoid repeating yourself.

To answer the question, "Should I even use a branded type", I think you should but I would like to offer a change of perspective about how to use your `io-ts` validations. [There is an interesting article](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) about using parsing logic at the edge of your app so that you can parse once and rely on stronger types within the core of the application.

I would therefore suggest that you parse the `Version` string as early as possible and then talk about the branded type everywhere else in the app. So for example, if the version comes in as a command line argument you could have something like:

```js
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function';
import * as t from 'io-ts';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';

// Version being the branded type
function useVersion(version: Version) {
  // Does something with the branded type
}

function main (args: unknown) {
  pipe(
    MyStructType.decode(args) // accepts unknown
    // Map is called on Right only and passes Lefts along so you can
    // focus in on specifically what to do if validation succeeded
    E.map(({ version }) => useVersion(version)),

    // later on maybe handle Left
    E.fold(
      (l: t.Errors): void => console.error(l),
      (r) => {},
    ),
  ),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll give the refinement approach a try and will get back.
On
"I would therefore suggest that you parse the Version string as early as possible and then talk about the branded type everywhere else in the app."

I full second that statement. The function `callFunction` is in this case the edge of my app. The app is actually a library and `callFunction` is part of the public API of that library. The idea is to validate the input that is passed into these library functions and then use the validated structures internally.

Comment: What is working fine for my usecase is to define an input type without branding and a refinement as an intersection of that type with branding, e.g. like so:

Answer (score 0):

What is working fine for my usecase is to define an input type without branding and a refinement as an intersection of that type with branding, e.g. like so:

```
export const TypeMyStructIn = type({
  version: string,
});

export const TypeMyStruct = intersection([
  TypeMyStructIn,
  type({
    version: TypeVersion,
  }),
]);

export type Version = TypeOf<typeof TypeVersion>;
export type MyStruct = TypeOf<typeof TypeMyStruct>;
export type MyStructIn = TypeOf<typeof TypeMyStructIn>;

export function callFunction(data: MyStructIn): boolean {
  // type check
  const validation = TypeMyStruct.decode(data);
  return isRight(validation);
}
```